# Loop through two unequal arrays simultaneously in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, laravel

I'm currently looping through an array in a Laravel 5 view file. This loop outputs party options from the database.

**parties.blade.php**

```
<div class="row clc-page-padding-left-right-46">
      @foreach($partyThemes as $key => $partyTheme)
        <div class="medium-6 large-3 columns">
          <div class="clc-block-shadowed" style="margin-bottom:0;min-height:375px;background-color:{{ $partyThemeColors[$key] }};">
            <center>
              <a href="#">
                <img src="{{ URL::asset( $partyTheme->image_main ) }}" alt="" />
              </a>
            </center>
            <h4 class="clc-text-align-center"><a href="#">{!! $partyTheme->title !!}</a></h4>
            <p class="clc-text-align-center">
              From R{!! $partyTheme->cost_per_child !!}
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="clc-text-align-center clc-more-info">
            <a href="#">More Info</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
```

I have another array which contains hexadecimal codes for the background colours. This is output on line 4 below in the style attribute.

```
$partyThemeColors = array(
  '#55cbbb',
  '#97c86b',
  '#fbdf5e',
  '#ea535d',
  '#97c86b',
  '#55cbbb',
  '#ea535d',
  '#fbdf5e'
);
```

Currently I'm using the $key of the main loop to select the value in the **$partyThemeColors** array.
Because the **$partyThemeColors** array is shorter than the other, once it finishes, it will throw an error.

How can I get the **$partyThemeColors** array to reset back to the beginning once it has reached the end?

This is basically running two loops simultaneously, which contain arrays of varying lengths?

Comment: get the number of values of the shorter array and  do a `for loop` based on that value.

Comment: Some kind of check if the value is null and start a new foreach if true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```php
$partyThemeColors[$key % count($partyThemeColors)]
```

You may want to extract the count from within the loop.

Comment: Doesn't the first iteration divide by 0?

Comment: I believe it should be the other way around: `$key % count($partyThemeColors)`. The count is the base number which you don't want to meet or exceed.